# Merge two files. First row of f1 and first row of f2 and so on in the new file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a requirement in which i have some 2000+ rows in each file1 and file2. file1 rows are related corresponding to file2 rows.
I want to merge the files together such that First row of f1 and first row of f2 and so on in the new file. Example:

```
file1.csv :
===========
foo, dummy, data, test
a, b, c, d

file2.csv :
===========
foo1, dummy1, data1, test1
e, f, g, h

NewFile:
========

foo, dummy, data, test
foo1, dummy1, data1, test1
a, b, c, d
e, f, g, h
```

Sed, AWK anything would work for me.

Comment: quite easy to do with `paste`... and this forum is about getting help with code you tried, not about asking entire solution to questions

Answer (score 0):

Simple `paste` approach:

```
paste -d'\n' file1.csv file2.csv
```

- `-d'\n'` - merged lines delimiter